# Sublime Text 2 not detecting python library if installed in /opt

Tags: python, sublime-text

I am attempting to install [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/) in /opt/sublime_text. Once all the files are in there, I believe the executable not detecting the python libraries and throwing the following error:

[image]

- I have python installed on my system already (2.7.3).
- I am able to run Sublime Text 2 from my home directory.

I've tried copying just the `__future__.pyo` file into the /opt/sublime_text folder but I get the same error message.

Is there a solution which doesn't require me to extract all of the python libraries in the application folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have an lib/python26.zip package within the app folder. Check if this file is possible corrupted.

Comment: Thanks, you were right. I was not properly copying the files. Rechecking my process and making sure all the files were intact fixed my problem.